# Element:Text and sub elements combined in PowerBI & XML

Tags: excel, xml, text, powerbi, element

Having an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><outer>
    <inner>Some text.</inner>
    <inner>More text.</inner>
</outer>
```

and the following PowerBI script

```
let
    Table0 = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("simple1.xml")){0}[Table]
in
    Table0
```

you get this

| Element:Text |
| --- |
| Some text. |
| More text. |

---

Now I'd like to add sub elements and keep inner.Element:Text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><outer>
    <inner>Some text.<secret>Don't care.</secret></inner>
    <inner>More text.<secret>You know.</secret></inner>
</outer>
```

Using the same PowerBI script as above you get

| secret |
| --- |
| Don't care. |
| You know. |

I already tried this script

```
let
    Table0 = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("simple2.xml")),
    Table1 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table0, "Table", {"secret"})
in
    Table1
```

but got this

| Name | secret |
| --- | --- |
| inner | Don't care. |
| inner | You know. |

But I'd like to get this:

| Element:Text | secret.Element:Text |
| --- | --- |
| Some text. | Don't care. |
| More text. | You know. |

My current **workaround** (which I'd like to avoid) is to use `sed` to wrap the element text of an inner entry in its own sub element:

```
<inner><text>Some text.</text><secret>Don't care.</secret></inner>
```

Comment: Is it enough to match these two values? Will more different value come between models?

Comment: There are actually thousands of "inner" elements. It's just that a certain sub element containts text and further sub elements. And I got Excel UI to display element text only if it does not contain sub elements.